# SQL Replace quando alguma variável contém ponto e vírgula

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou utilizando este comando sem problemas para substituir `class="texto1"` por `class="texto2"`:

```
UPDATE tabela
SET estilo = REPLACE (estilo,'class="texto1"','class="texto2"')
WHERE estilo LIKE 'class="texto1"';
```

Funciona perfeitamente, porém quando quero substituir `class="texto1" style="width:20px;margin-top:5px` que tem ponto e vírgula `;` recebo está mensagem de erro:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'FROM `tabela` WHERE 1' at line 1

O comando utilizado na segunda tentativa foi este:

```
UPDATE tabela
SET estilo =
REPLACE (estilo,
         'class="texto1" style="width:20px;margin-top:5px"',
         'class="texto3"')
WHERE estilo LIKE '%class="texto1" style="width:20px;margin-top:5px"%';
```

O que poderia estar ocasionando o erro?

Comment: Procurei ferramentas online de "character escape" mas nenhuma modificou o trecho com o ponto e vírgula.

Comment: Por favor, especifique melhor tua pergunta, texto velho e texto1?

Comment: Gostaria de substituir 'class="texto1" style="width:20px;margin-top:5px' por 'class="texto3' mas recebo o erro apresentado acima.

Comment: @Wesley: é MySQL ou SQL Server? A mensagem de erro indica MySQL mas a tag sql-server está marcada. Poderia verificar?

Comment: @JoséDiz é um banco de dados sql rodando em lynx pela LocaWeb, sou leigo no assunto, removi a tag sql-server, gostaria de fazer a alteração através do phpmyadmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui utilizando comando abaixo:

```
UPDATE `tabela`
SET `estilo` = 'class="text3"'
WHERE `estilo` LIKE 'class="text3" style="width:120px;text-align:center;"'
```

O erro só é apresentado se clicar em "Simular pesquisa", mas se clicar em "Executar" funcionará normalmente.

Comment: Nossa, tem 2 horas que estou quebrando a cabeça e a resposta era essa, ele dá erro apenas em "Simular pesquisa". Quanta inconsistência, não? Como de fato acreditar que a simulação será igual a execução?

Answer (score 0):

Como vc esta chamando esse SQL?

Se for em c# tu pode montar a string assim:

```
var sql = string.Format(@"UPDATE tabela SET estilo = REPLACE (estilo, '{0}', '{1}') where estilo LIKE '%class="{2}';", valor1, valor2, valor3);
```

Tu pode tb usar uma stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SubstituiTexto]
    @antigo varchar(50),
    @novo varchar(50),
    @valor varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
   UPDATE tabela SET estilo = REPLACE (estilo, @antigo, @novo) where estilo LIKE @valor
END
```

e chama a sp assim: `exec substituitexto 'texto1','texto2','texto3'`

Comment: Boa noite Roger, desculpe, é a primeira vez que abro uma pergunta nessa área, esqueci de especificar, mas gostaria de executar o comando através do phpmyadmin, não consegui utilizar nenhuma das opções acima